# svn export and commit back to server

Tags: svn

I am building a script which will checkout a single file from svn and I need to edit it and commit it back to the server.

After looking around I understood that `svn export` is used to clone a single file and `svn checkout` cannot be used.

But, as `svn export` doesn't clone a working copy I am unable to commit it. On the other hand `svn checkout` doesn't suite my requirement.

**Question:** Is there any way to checkout a single file which has a working copy to commit back to the server from **command line (windows)**

Thanks a lot

Comment: About the best you can do is to have a full `svn checkout` somewhere, then you can `svn export` interesting files elsewhere, modify them, and then in your checked-out location, run `svn up`, copy your modified files in, and then `svn commit`...

Comment: @twalberg: I did that first and then realized that the repository size was too huge and it was taking a lot of time just to edit one file.

Comment: if having a working copy doesn't fit your requirements, then svn doesn't fit your requirements.  Sounds like a requirements problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind doing the svn command twice, you can *checkout* a single file using this method:

```
$ svn co --depth=empty http://svn.vegicorp.net/svn/proj
$ cd proj
$ svn up foo.txt
A      foo.txt
$ vi foo.txt   # Change foo.txt
$ svn commit -m"Modified foo.txt for the heck of it"
sending    foo.txt
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 194833
```

The `--depth=empty` checks out your project and creates a working directory. However, it doesn't download any files in that working directory. Then, you can update the files you want which will download only those files. Here I'm downloading foo.txt to edit.

Once you're done, you can commit the changes and you've modified just one file without downloading the entire directory.

---

#### One little question

Exactly why are you doing this? I ask because usually when I see something like this, I find out that the build process is doing something <strike>wrong</strike> *sub-opitmally*. For example, one site was taking WSDL files, creating the Java source files from the WSDL, and then checking in the generated Java source files. I had to convince them that if they did their build correctly, they'd be automatically generating the Java source files during the build process, and there would be no reason to commit them.

I am not saying it should never be done. For example, you maybe updating a versioning file in this particular context, and want it saved as part of your versioning since the source code will use this file. It's that a process like this usually raises a flag for me. If I knew the reason, I might be able to suggest a better alternative.

Comment: Answering to your question, I am building a client side program on windows using ruby which integrates with my ruby on rails web application. SVN Repository files are listed in there, the user clicks on a edit button for a single file he wishes to on the web page that he wants to edit and I have my own URL handler to accept that and run the program on the client machine. So the first thing I need to do is checkout that single file in a temp folder and then edit the file with a final default commit message.

Comment: Sounds like something you should be using the Ruby bindings for.

Comment: @BenReser I will try that to check if suits my requirement. Thanks

Comment: If you have issues please post a question here or send an email to the users@subversion.apache.org list.  I did a presentation about the bindings that may be helpful to you (examples in the zip file): http://ben.reser.org/svn/auto-svn/

Answer (score 1):

You won't have a working copy but for a single file use `svn cat` and [`svnmucc`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnmucc.re.html) (this has been around as a additional tool since 1.5.0 and a standard command since 1.8.0, it was called mucc under contrib before that).

```
svn cat $URL > file
# edit file
svnmucc -m 'my log message' put file $URL
```

If you want to diff before commit you'll have to keep your own copy of the original file around, so possibly before modifying `copy file file.orig`.  Also this will wipe out any changes that have been made by commits that were made between when you get the file and when you do the put.

There is however a slightly more complicated way around this that deals with that.

```
rev=`svn info $URL | awk '/^Revision:/ { print $2}'`
svn cat -r $rev $URL > file
#edit file
svnmucc -m 'my log message' -r $rev put file $URL
```

In this case you'll have to keep track of the revision that you retrieved with cat and if that the file has changed since that revision you'll get an out of date error like you would with a checkout.

I realize the person asking was on Windows and the above example isn't directly applicable there (since I used unix shell).  The issue that this is rather annoying on platforms without handy tools like awk hasn't gone unnoticed by SVN devs and so Subversion will have a new command in the command line client that makes this easier in 1.9 (`svn youngest`).

Comment: what happens if there were changesets that altered that file between the export and the smucc put?

Comment: I updated the question to deal with the scenario that @thekbb brought up, probably should have done that in my original answer.